# Is it possible to have nested submodules be siblings of eachother?

Tags: git

I have a repository that contains a submodule A.

Submodule A contains a submodule B.

So when I clone my repository and run `git submodule update --init --remote --recursive`, I end up with a directory structure like so...

```
Repository
|___A
    |___B
```

Is it possible to have my directory structure look like so...

```
Repository
|___A
|___B
```

while still having repo B being a submodule of repo A?

Comment: Relationships in Git are either parent/child or sibling, but never both at the same time.

Comment: @torek So does that mean to achieve this effect I have to just make repo A and B a submodule of my main repository - eventhough it makes sense for B to be included inside of A?

Comment: If you want that particular layout, yes. If you don't mind having `B` appear in two different places, you can let it appear in both places. If your OS has the concept of symbolic links, you can store a symlink in the top level repo that makes `B` an alias for `A/B`.